# Pronunciation: Ｗ杯?

Tags: pronunciation

From [Jim Breen's EDICT](http://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/entr.py?svc=jmdict&sid=&e=1104950):

> ワールドカップ, 
>   ダブルはい
>   【Ｗ杯】

What is most commonly used?

Is W ever pronounced the same as 'W' in English and not ダブル?

Will people ever say:

ダブルカップ?

ワールドはい?

---

I know everyone keeps refering to:

> [Pronunciation of W](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/pronunciation-of-w)

but that still doesnt answer my question if people ever just use the pronunciation of English 'W' to say Japanese 'W' - I mean there is a clear difference between W and ダブル.

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/pronunciation-of-w　this regarding ダブル

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just from living in Japan, speaking to Japanese people, and more than anything consuming lots of Japanese media...

ワールドカップ is **by far** the most common.
だぶるはい I feel like should exist but I can't actually remember the last time I heard someone say this.
[ダブルカップ](http://tabelog.com/restaurant/images/Rvw/14862/640x640_rect_14862647.jpg), ワールドはい no.

If you need some extra evidence I found a [chiebukuro post](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1041153090) where the answers basically back me up that ワールドカップ is the most common.

> 1.ワールドカップ以外の読み方を聞いたことがありません。
>
> 2.基本どんな読み方でも悪くはないけどワールドカップって読む人が多いですよね～
>
> 3.サッカーとか知らないような人だったら、もしかして読むかも知れませんが、普通は読みません。というか、W杯って言葉なんですけど、何かに書いたりするような時に、ワールドカップという言葉を短縮するのには使ったりしますけど、会話ではワールドカップとは言いますけど、一般的にW杯とは会話では言いませんよね！？
>   etc etc

The pronunciation of W in Japanese is discussed [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/pronunciation-of-w).

Answer (score 4):

W杯 is not meant to be pronounced. No one knows how to say this out loud "correctly".

If conveying the meaning is important, I would read this as "ワールドカップ", maybe after one second of consideration. It's like saying "The First World War" for WWI.

If what's literally written on the paper is important, I would say "ダブリュー・はい", knowing this is an unusual way to refer to The World Cup. It's like saying "double-u, double-u, ai" for WWI.

The *correct* way to say "W", I believe, is ダブリュー. Announcers always say "ダブリュー、ダブリュー、ダブリュー、ドット、グーグル、ドット、コム" for "www.google.com".

I always pronounce W as ダブル only when it clearly means *double*, *second*, or *extra* ([Wチャンス](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=W%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9&tbm=isch)). But I hear many Japanese people say ダブル regardless of the context, probably because ダブル is easier to pronounce.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence.